# python selenium to selected a radio button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am working on a python selenium code to try to click a radio button. Here is the html code:

```
<tbody>
   <tr class="row-event">
      <td class="selection-cell"><input type="radio" class=""></td>
      <td>812589</td>
      <td>john</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-event">
      <td class="selection-cell"><input type="radio" class=""></td>
      <td>909720</td>
      <td>bob</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to click the radio-button where it is of the same row that containing "812589" value. How may this "target" being defined in the following code.

```
def clickTargetRadio(self):
    by = By.XPATH
    target = ""   # ???
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, target))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath :

```
//td[.='812589']/preceding-sibling::td[1]/input
```

We look for an `input` element, child of the first `td` preceding-sibling of a `td` element containing `812589`.

Imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[.='812589']/preceding-sibling::td[1]/input"))).click()
```